# How to find a male and a female D connectors 15 pins, in altium designer Summer 09?

Tags: pcb-design

I need to design a adaptor with a male and two female connectors, pin to pin connected. The connector is a D connector 15 pins.
I found a D connector 15, that was what I was looking for, however, I don't know how to encounter its match. They have different names ? I know the pin numbering are mirrored, but I do not want to do it manually and take the risk of make a mistake.
Does someone know something about how to find it ? I'm using Altium designer Summer 09.

Comment: It is almost always better to make your own footprints. Grab the datasheet and proceed from there. The Altium libraries are considered for reference, not as a good production level libraries.

Comment: You should just make them. You can add 3D models, make the part  numbers match your preferred supplier etc.

Answer (score 1):

you may easily find schematic and footprint in snapeda.com

https://www.snapeda.com/parts/1-1734530-1/TE%20Connectivity/view-part/?ref=search&t=d-sub%2015

3D files can be found in grabcad, 3dcontent, pcb-3d